# jsf 2.x use a similar <c:set> behavior inside a <h:datatable>

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

I am trying a jsf 2.x <h:datatable> and I need something like a <c:set> behavior inside it. Here is my code,

```
<h:column id="passCol">
    <f:facet id="passFct" name="header">Password</f:facet>
    <h:inputText value="#{tech.password}" rendered="#{(tech.id).trim() == (technicianBean.technicianId).trim()}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{tech.password}" rendered="#{(tech.id).trim() != (technicianBean.technicianId).trim()}"/>
</h:column>
```

What I am pretending should be as follows,

```
<h:column id="passCol">
    <f:facet id="passFct" name="header">Password</f:facet>
            <c:set property="inputField" target="#{myBean}" value="#{tech.password}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.inputField}" rendered="#{(tech.id).trim() == (technicianBean.technicianId).trim()}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{tech.password}" rendered="#{(tech.id).trim() != (technicianBean.technicianId).trim()}"/>
</h:column>
```

being tech the var setting in the datatable. This way I can catch tech.password into my input field what let me work with it (e.g.: an update).

How can I achieve this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: What problem do you have setting `#{tech.password}` in your `h:inputText` directly?

Comment: `#{tech.password}` is not a field of the bean so I can not process it. It is the value I want to catch into myBean.inputField that yes let me process inside myBean.

Comment: Hang on, `#{tech.password}` is a field from one of your POJO entities I suppose? If you're displaying your datatable inside a form when sending it the POJO should acquire the value you specified in the `inputText`...

Comment: Yes, that is it and the question is how can I pass this value to my bean using `h:inputText`?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the concept. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

JSF already has the reference of the collection of elements it's iterating over. So having that case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head />
<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.itemsList}" var="item">

            <h:column>
                <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>

        <h:commandButton action="#{bean.update}" value="submit" />
    </h:form>


</h:body>
```

Even `#{item.value}` is not directly referencing the managed bean, it is an input component, so JSF knows where to write its value. If you use it with this managed bean you'll notice when clicking 'submit' the list of values the table is referencing to is being updated. Indeed, this code will print out the updated values of the list when you click the button.

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    public class Item {

        private String value;

        public Item(String val) {
            value = val;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item [value=" + value + "]";
        }

    }

    private List<Item> itemsList = Arrays.asList(new Item("value1"), new Item(
            "value2"));

    public List<Item> getItemsList() {
        return itemsList;
    }

    public void update() {
        System.out.println(itemsList);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Xtreme Biker, I was thinking of something like your answer but exactly as you do is a better solution than mine.

Comment: Glad to see it helped you! Remember you can mark the answer as correct clicking the check mark (✓) on the left side of it. ;-)